# jQuery Clone several "li" and append at a specific position of ul (not its end)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am developping a dynamic pagination bar , where the "li" are cloned  n times depending of a number received from an external webservice.

**here is my pagination element:**

```
<ul class="pagination">
            <li class="pagePrevious" name="previous">
                <a href="#" aria-label="Previous"> <span aria-hidden="true">«</span> </a>
            </li>

            <li class="page" name="1"><a href="#" class="is-active">1</a></li>

            <li class="pageNext" name="next">
                <a href="#" aria-label="Next"> <span aria-hidden="true">»</span> </a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

evidently you may note that my first Li and my last Li inside the Ul are the button next and previous which are not cloned and they are statically always present .

my cloning fonction consits of selecting the last-1 child of the li which is directly the second , and clone it with dynamic incremental id , and finally its inserts it in the ul.

**my fonction :**

```
createPagination: function (nb) {
            var lastLI = $('.pagination li').last().prev();
            var num = lastLI.attr('name');

            for (var i = num; i <= nb ; i++) {
                if (i != num) {
                    var cloned = lastLI.clone().attr('name', i);
                    $(cloned).find('a').text(i);
                    $('ul').append(cloned);
                }
            }
        }
```

**my problem is how to make it append the cloned li always before the last li of next button. ???
note that i mays not change the name of class attribute for other specifications**

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.before()` to put something immediately before another element.

```
createPagination: function (nb) {
    var nextLI = $('pagination .pageNext');
    var lastLI = nextLI.prev();
    var num = lastLI.attr('name');

    for (var i = num+1; i <= nb ; i++) {
        var cloned = lastLI.clone().attr('name', i);
        cloned.find('a').text(i);
        nextLI.before(cloned);
    }
}
```

BTW, you don't need to write `$(cloned)`, since `cloned` is already a jQuery object. And if you start the `for` loop at `num+1`, you don't need to check `if (i != num)`.

Comment: my  problem is not the clone action , but how to append it in a specific position :  $('ul').append(clone)  ----> the position is the last

Comment: `lastLI` is the 2nd-to-last LI, so putting it after that puts it before the LI with `Next` in it.

Comment: var nextLI= $('.pagination li').last()  ; clone.insertBefore(nextLI);  that its the solution

Comment: Yeah, my original answer was putting them backwards, I was just updating it.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use simlply the fonction insertBefore instead of append :

```
var lastLI = $('.pagination li').last().prev();
            var nextLI= $('.pagination li').last();
            var num = lastLI.attr('name');

            for (var i = num; i <= nb ; i++) {
                if (i != num) {
                    var clone = lastLI.clone().attr('name', i);
                    $(clone).find('a').text(i);
                    clone.insertBefore(nextLI);
                    clone.removeClass("is-active")
                }
            }
```